# emacs delete-selection-mode disables itself

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs, emacs24

In my `.emacs` file I have `(delete-selection-mode t)` to enable the [delete-selection-mode](http://emacswiki.org/DeleteSelectionMode) globally. Currently I'm working on a TeX file with AUXTeX, so it might be related to AUCTeX, but I don't know.

At first, after visiting a file `foo.tex` everything works fine, and typing over a marked text replaces the marked text with the one I type. However, after some time, during which I compile the document, add TeX macros, etc. the functionality of the `delete-selection-mode` doesn't work any more.

I don't know which action of mine is the one which causes the problem - it would be hard to trace it.

Note that although the functionality of the `delete-selection-mode` fails, when I try to enable it (`M-x delete-selection-mode`) I get a message that the mode was *disabled*! That is it was not disabled before - it just didn't work... I I then enable it (`M-x delete-selection-mode` again), then it is enabled and working again. Till the next fail...

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood, the mode use `pre-command-hook`, which allows commands to run things right before every command. Emacs is known to clear this variable in the event of an error (just to make sure that Emacs don't hang). This mean that the function used by `delete-selection-mode`, *or any other mode that use this hook*, triggered an error.

How to fix it? Find what caused the error, wrap the function in a `ignore-errors` block, or run a timer re-adding the function every ten seconds or so.